# SQLite + android : Select integer to know if it's 0 or 1

Tags: android, sqlite, select, integer

i search since few hours how to select an integer column (as a boolean) and know if it's a 0 was insert or a 1 was insert.

I tried like this :

```
    public boolean getLucide(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT luciditeCarnetreve FROM Carnetreve WHERE luciditeCarnetreve = ?";
    db.rawQuery(query, null);
    return true;
}
```

But the problem in my code it's the method return always true so always 1.
How can i get this with cursor ?

Comment: it return true because retrun true will always return true

Comment: just you need the value inserted ..if 0 or 1 retrun it as boolean true or false??@M. Dupont

Comment: Yes this method is use to setCheck a button, if it's 1, i check the button if it's 0 is not check

Comment: you need just the inserted value ? if the value in the db is 0 the return type should be false??

Comment: Yes it's just what i need but i don't know how to handle this

Comment: check my answer @M. Dupont...hope it help you...if ok mark it as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public boolean getLucide()
    {
        int integervalue = 0;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select luciditeCarnetreve from Carnetreve  where luciditeCarnetreve  = '"+somevalue+"' ",null);
        while(c.moveToNext())
        {
            integervalue = c.getInt(0);//put the number of coloumn nunbering start from 0
        }
        c.close();
        return integervalue > 0 ? true : false ;
    }
```

Comment: thx for help but "somevalue" in the request don't need to be passed in parameter of the method ?

Comment: its depend on your needs...if the answer fit your needs mark it as correct @M.Dupont

Comment: Yes but with "return integervalue > 0" we return always true

Comment: it will return true incase integervalue is one if integervalue  is zero it will return false@M.Dupont